# Ruby: Bundle fails with json (gem native extension)

Tags: ruby, json, rubygems

When I use bundler to install my gems on Windows 7, all of them are installed except json.
My error message is the following:

[image: Screenshot of error]
**...**

[image]

What I already did was:

- Reinstalled everything
- Tried other versions of json
- Installed Ruby Development Kit

Comment: Which version of the development kit? Which version of Ruby?

Comment: **Ruby 2.1.5** and
**DevKit-mingw64-64-4.7.2-20130224-1432-sfx**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to reproduce your error by installing the **32-bit** version of Ruby and the **64-bit** version of the DevKit. The versions must match!

Uninstall Ruby and then install the 64-bit version: Ruby 2.1.5 (x64)

Comment: Ok, thanks. I will try this out. I will tell you, if it worked then.

Comment: Worked fine for me :)